# Jquery form submit not working when query string is present in URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Test scenario:

1. Type "hello" in the textbox, you should see "hello" written in the page
2. Now click the "test" link (it's just a link to itself with a query string `&test=1`)
3. Now type "world" in the textbox, you can see that it doesn't get written in the page anymore.

Why is this happening?

You can test this page on a `.php` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="search_form" method="post">
        <label for="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" id="search" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#search_form').submit(function (event) {         
            window.location.href = '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?s='?>' + $('#search').val();
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    </script>   

    <br /><br />

    <?php $s = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 's'); ?>

    Query string: <?=$s?>

    <br /><br />

    <a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?s=<?=$s?>&test=1">test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo URL: (removed after problem solved)

Comment: Please elaborate what happens the second time

Comment: @Diego I am expecting the form to work (e.g., print what the user enters in the texbox) even after clicking "test" link.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But what is happening instead?

Comment: @Diego nothing gets printed

Comment: Could you post the final URL and its source?

Comment: Check your console for errors and make sure you have included the jQuery library

Comment: Why would it Print anything? I see no `echo` or `print`

Comment: @Twisty  `<?=` is shorthand for echo

Comment: @M.Doye thanks. I have never used it or seen it. Will check it out.

Comment: @M.Doye, I believe that he is including jQuery because the first time works.

Comment: @Diego I have edited the question with demo URL

Comment: @Diego ahh.. I see..

Comment: @IMB, It works perfect!!

Comment: @Diego when you click "test" it will stop working

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?s=' + $('#search').val();`, I think your breaking from the string wrong.

Comment: @Twisty tried that one, still didn't work

Comment: Also since your using JQM, you may want to add `data-ajax="false"` to your `A` Test tag.

Comment: Try wrapping the jQuery script with `$(function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: @Twisty that works! put that as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Jquery Mobile, all links are executed via AJAX by default. This will confuse this script of yours. I would suggest suppressing this in the link.

`<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?s=<?=$s?>&test=1" data-ajax="false">test</a>`

This will allow the link to be treated like normal and will execute the URL without AJAX.

Comment: Also, you can improve your JQM code a little too. Some suggestions: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xhtdf0e2/